# Storing document in couchbase using spring-data

Tags: java, spring-data, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I am using spring-data-couchbase for CRUD operations. When i am trying to store a document in couchbase the document is getting stored like:

```
{
_class": "com.test.Document",
  "lastUpdatedDateTime": 1589543147404,
  "ElementsList": [
    {
      "quantity": {
        "scale": 0,
        "intVal": {
          "signum": 0,
          "bitLength": 0,
          "mag": [],
          "lowestSetBit": 0,
          "bitCount": 0,
          "firstNonzeroIntNum": 0
        },
        "intCompact": 0,
        "precision": 1,
        "stringCache": "0"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I am not able to understand why _class is appearing in the document, and why in the ElementList the quantity has become a json as well when in the actual it is just a String. When i try and convert the Document to JSON, it appears like:

```
{
  "lastUpdatedDateTime": 1589543147404,
   "ElementList":[
     {
       "quantity": 0
     }
   ]
}
```

The Couchbase version i am using is: 6.5 and spring version is 2.2.4-RELEASE

Comment: Would you mind posting a minimum sample of the Java that you've written that results in the data being stored like that?

Comment: Hi Matthew, I guess I found out the issue. The quantity variable is BigDecimal and I am quite confident that spring-data is actually saving the variable with scale, signum etc details. Using a custom convertor stored it as expected.